# Remove Enter Parameter Value

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, datediff

I'm trying to calculate the time difference between two variables. The first variable is checkin_time and the second variable is triage_time. Both variables contain values with the same format, for example... 12/31/2018  3:24:00 PM.

So in theory I would be subtracting Checkin_time (12/31/2018  3:24:00 PM) from Triage_time (12/31/2018  4:24:00 PM) to get 60 minutes.

I'm using the following code to calculate the time difference

```
Select DateDiff(Minute,CHECKIN_TIME,triage_time) AS triagetime
From TAT_Import
```

but when executing this query I'm getting an 'enter paramteer value' pop up box and it's asking me to enter a value for minutes.

How do I run my query without having to enter a value for minutes in the pop up box?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DateDiff`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datediff-function-e6dd7ee6-3d01-4531-905c-e24fc238f85f) function requires a string as the first argument, hence your code should be:

```sql
select DateDiff("n", CHECKIN_TIME, triage_time) AS triagetime
from TAT_Import
```

Comment: @lee_MAc  Thanks but I'm still getting the pop up box using this code

Comment: @Greg What is the popup box prompting you to specify? Are all of your fields spelt correctly?